# what is the best way audio live stream to android clients using .net APIs

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, audio, stream, broadcast

I want create a web radio app using .net, that have scheduled audio track list and it's playing from my web app. android client can listen currently playing audio tracks.
That is a requirement.

Comment: 1) there is no best way. 2) what is a problem for you to do what you want?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I want create web app that have uploaded audio track list, then i want play all tracks one by one on the web from pre-defined track lineup. after that currently running track broadcast from web app. and android client can receive track through web API or something and parallel playing with web. that's i want.

Comment: that's not what I asked. I asked `what is a problem`, not that you want. What is a problem for you to implement what you want?

Comment: and why did you remove the `android` tag?

Comment: Basically i haven't any experience with  **audio streaming** with .net or java, so my problem is what should i use (streaming technologies, libraries, plugins)  to achieve that. (still i haven't started programming and i'm searching for some architecture to this project, that's y i need understanding about best suitable technology for my project)

Comment: Currently android is not needed & in this moment web streaming is only one important to me.

Answer (score 0):

So if you're using .net core 2.x then a good starting point might be this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AudioController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return File(System.IO.File.OpenRead("song.mp3"), "audio/mpeg", true);
    }
}
```

If it's .Net Framework [this article may help](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asynchronous-videos-live-streaming-with-asp-net-web-apis-2-0/)